# How to pass a text from <li> to Textbox when clicked?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

```
<asp:Textbox id="ToSend" runat="server" Width="300px"></asp:Textbox>

<ul>
<li value="smile" class="smile">example 1</li>
<li value="smile" class="smile">example 2</li>
</ul>
```

This is my textbox.

```
$(".smile").click(function () {
    $('#ToSend').val($(this).text());
});
```

I'm still new and I found a lot of code are passing the text to input type="text", but I want it to pass to my `<asp:Textbox></Textbox>`.

Comment: you should know what you see as <asp:Textbox /> will be converted to <input type="text"> with all that being said check my answer in afew mins.

Comment: Basically <asp:Textbox> would be rendered as <input>. So it is not clear, what is there problem

Comment: tell me, u want to send values or texts?

Comment: i want send the texts

Comment: well both answer works :)

Comment: @Valkyriee thanks alot, is working now :)

Comment: Glad it worked, don't forget to accept the solution =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind click event handler to `li` elements and select input element by generated id.

```
<asp:Textbox ID="ToSend" runat="server" Width="300px"></asp:Textbox>

$('ul.txt li').click(function(){
  $('#<%= ToSend.ClientID %>').val($(this).text());
})
```

Comment: @ZunPing : glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

in additional to Pranav's answer here is the general way to do it:

```
$('.txt li').on('load',function() {
    var _value =  $(this).text();
    $("input[id='ToSend']").val(_value);
})
```